# Can we solve $\frac{\cos x \sin x+\cos y \sin y}{\cos x+\sin y}$ further?

Tags: trigonometry

I was solving a mechanics question in physics, where I came across the following expression which I am not able to evaluate.

How to evaluate this:

$$\frac{\cos x \sin x+\cos y \sin y}{\cos x+\sin y}$$

Help would be genuinely appreciated. Thanks.

---

*I know it is not a very well-framed question, but I have no approach. Sorry.*

Comment: Write \sin and \cos insted of just cos and sin and then you do not need to put those extra spaces there. I corrected it for you this time.

Comment: What do you mean by *I am not able to evaluate*? If $x,y$ are given, you're perfectly able to evaluate that quantity. What are you willing to do with it?

Comment: Why do you want to evaluate this further? What are you trying to achieve? It's very vague otherwise, like shooting arrows in the air.

Comment: Is there a specific trigonometric identity for the question, like we have $$\sin(a+b) = \sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b $$ Basically I want to reduce the equation into something that looks more concise.

Comment: @Phymathechem And why do you want to do so? What's your ultimate goal?

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is equivalent to

$$\frac{\sin 2x+\sin 2y}{2(\cos x+\sin y)}.$$

There's little more that you can say.

Comment: Can you edit and add the steps and identities you used please

Comment: It should be $\sin y$ in the denominator instead of $\sin x$.

Comment: @mag Yep. In any case the formula is ugly :-)

Answer (score 1):

$$\cfrac{\cos x \sin x+\cos y \sin y}{\cos x+\sin y}=\cfrac{\frac 12[\sin (2x)+ \sin (2y)]}{\cos x+\sin y}=\dfrac{1}{2(\cos x+\sin y)}\left[2\sin\frac{2x+2y}{2}\cos\frac{2x-2y}{2}\right]=\dfrac{\sin (x+y)\cos (x-y)}{\cos x+\sin y}$$
**Formulae:** $$\sin\: x\cdot \cos\:y=\frac{1}{2}[\sin(x+y)+\sin(x-y)]\\\sin\: x+\sin\: y=2\sin\frac{x+y}{2}\cos\frac{x-y}{2}$$